# How to splitt a string to an array with keys and values using php

Tags: php, arrays

I have string and I want to splitt it to array and remove a specific part and then convert it back to a string .

```
$string = "width,100;height,8600;block,700;narrow,1;"
```

I want to search block in this string and remove it with its value "block,700;" and get the string as "width,100;height,8600;narrow,1;"

below is my code php which i tried.Please advice me

```
                $outerARR = explode(";", $string);
                $arr = array();
                foreach ($outerARR as $arrvalue) {
                    $innerarr = explode(",", $arrvalue);
                    $arr[] = $innerarr;
                }
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
                    if (in_array($arr, 'block')) {
                      unset($arr[$i]);

                    }
                }
```

Please note that "block" in aboive string will not always contain and the value may differ. So I can't use string replace . please advice

Comment: $string = str_replace('block,700;', '', $string);

Comment: @Fky :"block: wil not always include in the  string , and the value may differ. please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially want to replace part of your string:

```
$string = "width,100;height,8600;block,700;narrow,1;";
$regex = '#(block,(.*?);)#';
$result = preg_replace($regex, '', $string);
echo $result;
```

Comment: "block: wil not always include in string , and the value may differ. how to proceed

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$string = "width,100;height,8600;block,700;narrow,1;"
$outerARR = explode(";", $string);
$arr = array();
foreach ($outerARR as $arrvalue) {
    $innerarr = explode(",", $arrvalue);
    $arr[$innerarr[0]] = $innerarr[1];
}
if (array_key_exists('block', $arr)) {
    unset($arr['block']);
}
```